# How to build arrays in handling epoch time?

Tags: c

[instructions]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxOoo.png

This is the general instructions. I have made a program as to which you enter the given epoch time and it solves for each one separately, therefore you need to input 4 times. Example you input 1616580687, it first solves the days, which is 18710 days. Then you input it again and solves for the next, which is year == 2021, month == 3, and day == 24, and so on. How can I use arrays so that when I input 1616580687, it automatically gives out all the 4 values needed. For example, I input 1616580687, the output will be:

18710

2021 3 24

10 11 27

2021-03-24T10:11:27Z

PS. Fairly new to C here so I may not understand too technical terms. Been at C for about 2 months.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not describe code. Show code. Also please do not add links to pictures containing text. Inserting the instructions as text into the question is much more readable.

Comment: For more information about using SO please visit [the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then edit your question to add a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You do not need an array for this; you just need one variable that you pass to functions four times. It is not clear why you would have any problem with this. You should show some code you and explain your thinking.

Comment: @EricPostpischil how do i show my code? it says too long its over 1000 characters

Comment: Show **some** code. Show the code in the `main` routine. Show the portion of the code that calls the various functions. Tell us why you cannot put the time in some variable and then call different functions using the same variable. If you have some variable `x` that contains the time and was defined as `Instant x;`, then why cannot you call `daysAfterEpoch(x)` and later call `Instant_display(x)`? Why do you need an array instead of just using `x` twice?